# awstats. first time running script corrupts the log file

Tags: awstats

I have Awstats up and running on my server.
the script for generating info from the log files works perfectly for the first time. that means log file format and everything is fine.
after that If I run the script again.. all the following records are being recognized as corrupted...(I have changed the number of corrupted records limit to make sure this is the problem)
I have tried removing the log file and starting all over again. same thing. first time working after that not...
I suppose either 
the awstats changes something on then files which is not probable since this file is in use and no one can write in it.
or 
awstats have problem with jumping from the already processed records.

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In the first time you run update script; awstats analyzed all your log record and store the last line number in output summary file : PATH_TO_OUTPUT/awstats.domain.txt.

The next time you run script, it will start from saved line number;  if there no new log record in your log file it'll be corrupted.

If you want to try script run again, just delete your output file.

Awstats do not change anything in your log file. Just read from it.